# How to trigger jquery autocomplete manually on keyup

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, keyup

I want to trigger the jquery autocomplete manually on keyup, only after pressing the asterisk "*" by the end of the input.

Here's what I did:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="mainSearchBox">

var availableTags = [
   "Perl",
   "PHP",
   "Python",
   "Ruby"
];
$('input#mainSearchBox').keyup(function(){
    var value = $('input#mainSearchBox').val();
    if(value.substr(value.length - 1) == "*"){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength:0
        });
    } else {
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W56yq/152/)

Comment: Do you get any errors? How can we help you?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle ?

Comment: @Huelfe, yes I get this:
Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
throw new Error( msg );

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi, I did.

Comment: You are getting that error because you are closing the autocomplete when its not even initialized, i.e. Say you entered 'A' in you text box that moment autocomplete is not on the textbox because you initialize it only when user presses *. So at that moment you get this error.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi, OK, got it, any suggessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,
Try doing it like this :

```js
var availableTags = [
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby"
];
$('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  minLength: 0
});

$('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("disable");

$('input#mainSearchBox').keyup(function(e) {

  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  switch (code) {
    case 40: //down key
    case 38: //up key
    //add more cases for special buttons
      return;
  }

  var value = $('input#mainSearchBox').val();
  var last = value.substr(value.length - 1);
  if (last == "*") {
    var valToSearch = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
    $('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("enable");
    $('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("search", valToSearch);
  } else {
    $('input#mainSearchBox').autocomplete("disable");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" id="mainSearchBox">
```

Have a look at :

1. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search
2. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-enable
3. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-disable

What I have done :

1. Loaded/Initialized `autocomplete` on the textbox and then disabled it.
2. Whenever key-up event is triggered, I checked if last character in the input is `*`,

a. if it is, then enable `autocomplete` and force `search` on the text-box, with the input value without `*`. 
b. If it is not, then disable the autocomplete.

Comment: WoOow, that's perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,Having one question?if i do like that keyboard up and down selection is not working in autocomplete suggestion box.Can you please help about it?

Comment: Hey @iyyappan , refer the updated code. It supports Up and Down key.

Comment: Thanks for this, ended my 2 days streak of finding the solution.